# How convert String into Number in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting a Number that stored as a String from localstorage.

```js
   const numb = localstorage.getItem('value');
```

Now I want to convert it to a Number.
How can I achieve this.

**example**

`"5"` to `5`

Comment: `parse.Int("5")` sorry its `parseInt()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `parseInt()` to achive this.

```js
    parseInt(numb)
```

or you can use `+` operator too

```js
    +numb
```

Answer (score 2):

in order to change string to the number in angular, we can use "+" before our string to convert them to the string. for example we have :

```
  let x = "32";
  let y = +x;
  console.log(typeof y);  //number
  console.log(typeof x);  //string
```

Answer (score 1):

This will Work For you

```
 const numb = parse.Int(localstorage.getItem('value'));
```